# Select from arrays in a way similar to IN

Tags: postgresql, array

I have this table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[]
);

INSERT INTO sal_emp
VALUES
   ('Bil'  , '{1, 2, 3, 4}'),
   ('Bill2', '{5, 6, 7, 8}');
```

I can run query:

```
select name from sal_emp where pay_by_quarter @> ARRAY[1,4];
```

And got "Bil".

Is there a way to run a query like:

```
select name from sal_emp where pay_by_quarter @> ARRAY[1,4,5]
```

and get "Bil", "Bill2"?

Comment: The desired functionality is not properly defined in your question. Do you want the resulting arrays cover all elements of the array *together*? Or just any overlapping row like in the currently accepted answer? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overlap (&&) operator which means "have elements in common".

```
SELECT
    name
  FROM sal_emp
  WHERE
    pay_by_quarter && ARRAY[1,4,5]
```

Documentation link is here: [Array Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)